# How to convert setting variable from bash to tcsh

Tags: linux, csh, tcsh

I am trying to change my `bash` supported script to `tcsh` supported one.
In `bash` script, I have following:

```
SCRIPT_PATH="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
```

I tried to convert it to tcsh with following:

```
set sourced=($_)
set MY_PATH=`dirname $sourced[2]`
set SCRIPT_PATH=`cd $MY_PATH && pwd`
```

It works if I have to source it one time. But if I have to source it for more times, e.g., sourcing it from some other script, then it doesn't work.

Can someone help me fixing it the correct way for `tcsh`?

Comment: What's your motivation for converting your bash script to a tcsh script? tcsh is quite limited and almost universally discouraged for scripting; bash is really a much better environment.

Comment: As for your question: I'm not sure if there is a way to get the path to the currently source file in tcsh, only the running program. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: @Sweety Don't do that. [Google "csh why not"](https://www.google.com/search?q=csh+why+not).